# average number of different values in a column

Tags: matlab, average

I had a question in Matlab. It is so, I try to take average of the different number of values ​​in a column. For example, if we have the column below,

```
X = [1 1 2 3 4 3 8 2 1 3 5 6 7 7 5]
```

first I want to start by taking the average of 5 values ​​and plot them. In the case above, I should receive three averages that I could plot. Then take 10 values ​​at a time and so on.
I wonder if you have to write custom code to fix it.

Comment: X: looks like a row, but that is a coulmn!

Comment: If it's 1-dimensional, that doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

For a selected `N` (the number of values you want to take the average of):

```
N = 5;
mean_vals = arrayfun(@(n) mean(X(n-1+(1:N))),1:N:length(X))
```

Note: This does not check if `Index exceeds matrix dimensions`.

If you want to skip the last numbers, this should work:

```
mean_vals = arrayfun(@(n) mean(X(n-1+(1:N))),1:N:(length(X)-mod(length(X),N)));
```

To add the remaining values:

```
if mod(length(X),N) ~= 0
   mean_vals(end+1) = mean(X(numel(X)+1-mod(length(X),N):end))
end
```

**UPDATE:** This is a modification of [Eitan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17147501/2338750) first answer (before it was edited). It uses `nanmean()`, which takes the mean of all values that are not `NaN`. So, instead of filling the remaining rows with `zeros`, fill them with `NaN`, and just take the mean.

```
X = [X(:); NaN(mod(N - numel(X), N), 1)];
X_avg = nanmean(reshape(X, N, []));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I ran your code but got the problem that you said I could get,

Index Exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in @ (n) mean (X (n-1 + (1: N)))

I tried with other values ​​such as 2, and it worked. My column contains 390 values. I want to use N = 10, N = 20, N = 30 and N = 50. So my question is if it could be fixed for the N that I mentioned?

Comment: It could be fixed, yes. But it depends on whatyou want to do when the condition: `mod(length(X),N) == 0;` is not met (which is the case for `N=20` and `N = 50`). Do you want to skip the last 40 numbers? Suppose you want `N=3`, and take the mean of `X = [1 2 3 4]`. What do you plan to do with the 4?

Comment: If I understand correctly, so I can skip the values ​​that cause the problem, so that N = 10, 20, 30, 50 functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Do you want to skip the last numbers? (That would be the number 4 in my previous comment), or do you want to skip the N that causes the problem? That would be N=3 in my comment? In your case, only N=10, and N=30 works.

Comment: ok, only 10 and 30 works. I tried to say that i want to skip the values that couse the problem, or just take an average of the values ​​that remains, N does not affect anymore then.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is probably to rearrange your initial vector `X` into some matrix, with each column storing the required values to average:

```
A = reshape(X, N, []);
```

where `N` is the desired number of rows in the new matrix, and the empty brackets (`[]`) tell MATLAB to calculate the number of columns automatically. Then you can average each column using [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html):

```
X_avg = mean(A);
```

Vector `X_avg` stores the result. This can be done in one line like so:

```
X_avg = mean(reshape(X, N, []));
```

Note that the number of elements in `X` has to be divisible by `N`, otherwise you'll have to either pad it first (*e.g* with zeroes), or handle the "leftover" tail elements separately:

```
tail = mod(numel(X), N);
X_avg = mean(reshape(X(1:numel(X) - tail), N, [])); %// Compute average values
X_avg(end + 1) = mean(X(end - tail + 1:end));       %// Handle leftover elements
```

Later on you can put this code in a loop, computing and plotting the average values for a different value of `N` in each iteration.

#### Example #1

```
X = [1 1 2 3 4 3 8 2 1 3 5 6 7 7 5];
N = 5;

tail = mod(numel(X), N);
X_avg = mean(reshape(X(1:numel(X) - tail), N, []))
X_avg(end + 1) = mean(X(end - tail + 1:end))
```

The result is:

```
X_avg =
    2.2000   3.4000   6.0000
```

#### Example #2

Here's another example (this time the length of `X` is not divisible by `N`):

```
X = [1 1 2 3 4 3 8 2 1 3 5 6 7 7 5];
N = 10;

tail = mod(numel(X), N);
X_avg = mean(reshape(X(1:numel(X) - tail), N, []))
X_avg(end + 1) = mean(X(end - tail + 1:end))
```

The result is:

```
X_avg =
    2.8000   6.0000
```

Comment: +1, nice solution. I'm not completely sure what OP wants, but I guess it would make more sense to not include the zeros in the last column when calculating the mean...

Comment: @RobertP. That would be problematic if the number of elements in `X` is not a multiple of `N`. However, if the OP wishes not to include the padded zeroes in the computation, the last average value can be recalculated separately with `mean(X(end - mod(numel(X), N) + 1:end))`

Comment: @EitanT: I know that would be problematic using `reshape`, that's why I didn't propose a solution =P

Comment: @RobertP. I've edited the question to ignore the zeroes when averaging the last elements, when then length of `X` is not a multiple of `N`.

Comment: @Floris Yes, although it seems that OP is not interested in a moving average. The question states that for `N = 5` and `X` of length 10, the output is expected to have three values.

Comment: You are right, the OP only asked for the simple block average; I gave the alternative as well since it's actually quite efficient, and since it might be useful to the person asking the original question, or others stumbling onto this question.

Comment: @Floris it might be a good idea to clarify that in the answer itself to avoid confusion.

Comment: @EitanT: I updated my answer with a solution based on your first approach, but using `NaN`s instead of `zeros`. Hope that is OK.

Comment: @RobertP. Looks fine, except that it requires the Statistics Toolbox :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted some code and point out exactly what is not working.

As a first pointer. If

```
X = [1 1 2 3 4 3 8 2 1 3 5 6 7 7 5]
```

the three means in blocks of 5 you are interested in are

```
mean(X(1:5))
mean(X(6:10))
mean(X(11:15))
```

You will have to come up with a for loop or maybe some other way to iterate through the indices.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this (I didn't use Matlab in a while, I hope the syntax is right):

```
X = [1 1 2 3 4 3 8 2 1 3 5 6 7 7 5],
currentAmount=5,
block=0,
while(numel(X)<=currentAmount)
  while(numel(X)<=currentAmount+block*currentAmount)
    mean(X(block*currentAmount+1:block*currentAmount+currentAmount));
    block =block+1;
  end;
  currentAmount = currentAmount+5;
  block=0;
end
```

This code will first loop through all elements calculating means of 5 elements at a time. Then, it will expand to 10 elements. Then to 15, and so on, until the number of elements from which you want to make the mean is bigger than the number of elements in the column.

Comment: You need to store the mean value in a variable. In your case that would need to be a cell or struct, since it will be of varying length (dependent on `currentAmount`).

Comment: @RobertP. Thank's for the input, from the question I thought he may just want to plot the variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this operation a lot, it might be worth writing your own function for it. I would recommend using @EitanT's basic idea: pad the data, reshape, take mean of each column. However, rather than including the zero-padded numbers at the end, I recommend taking the average of the "straggling" data points separately:

```
function m = meanOfN(x, N)
% function m = meanOfN(x, N)
% create groups of N elements of vector x
% and return their mean
% if numel(x) is not a multiple of N, the last value returned
% will be for fewer than N elements
Nf = N * floor( numel( x ) / N ); % largest multiple of N <= length of x
xr = reshape( x( 1:Nf ), N, []);
m = mean(xr);
if Nf < N
  m = [m mean( x( Nf + 1:end ) )];
end
```

This function will return exactly what you were asking for: in the case of a 15 element vector with N=5, it returns 3 values. When the size of the input vector is not a multiple of N, the last value returned will be the "mean of what is left".

Often when you need to take the mean of a set of numbers, it is the "running average" that is of interest. So rather than getting `[mean(x(1:5)) mean(x(6:10)) mean(11:15))]`, you might want

```
m(1) = mean(x(1:N));
m(2) = mean(x(2:N+1));
m(3) = mean(x(3:N+2));
...etc
```

That could be achieved using a simple convolution of your data with a vector of ones; for completeness, here is a possible way of coding that:

```
function m = meansOfN(x, n)
% function m = meansOfN(x, n)
% taking the running mean of the values in x
% over n samples. Returns a row vector of size (sizeof(x) - n + 1)
% if numel(x) < n, this returns an empty matrix
mv = ones(N,1) / N; % vector of ones, normalized
m = convn(x(:), mv, 'valid'); % perform 1D convolution
```

With these two functions in your path (save them in a file called `meanOfN.m` and `meansOfN.m` respectively), you can do anything you want. In any program you will be able to write

```
myMeans = meanOfN(1:30, 5);
myMeans2 = meansOfN(1:30, 6);
```

etc. Matlab will find the function, perform the calculation, return the result. Writing your custom functions for specific operations like this can be very helpful - not only does it keep your code clean, but you only have to test the function once...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to average `K` random samples in your `N`-dimensional vector, then you could use:

```
N = length(X);
K = 20;    % or 10, or 30, or any integer less than or equal to N
indices = randperm(N, K);    % gives you K random indices from the range 1:N
result = mean(X(indices));   % averages the values of X at the K random 
                             % indices from above
```

A slightly more compact form would be:

```
K = 20;
result = mean(X(randperm(length(X), K)));
```

If you are just looking to take every `K` consecutive samples from the list and average them then I am sure one of the previous answers will give you what you want.